# Acoustic description of the realization [ɛə] of the North American raised /æ/

Tags: phonetics, north-american-english, vowels, ae-raising

The Wikipedia article on [/æ/ raising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//%C3%A6/_raising) uses the transcription [ɛə] for a realization of the North American raised /æ/, as in the words *ram* and *ran*. I'm having trouble interpreting this transcription, since there doesn't seem to be any acoustic description of this realization. If I'm reading the [IPA vowel chart](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5a/IPA_vowel_chart_2005.png) correctly, the transcription [ɛə] seems to indicate a higher first formant for [ɛ] and a lower first formant for [ə], so the formant transition would probably look something like this, which means the first formant transitions from high to low:

[image]

According to the transcription [ɛə], this realization starts with a lower vowel, [ɛ] (higher F1), and ends with a higher vowel, [ə] (lower F1)

But based on my crude speech analyses of two North American speakers with Praat, the first formant seems to transition from low to high. Notice how the bottom line in each spectrogram curves up, not down.
[image]
[image]

To me, it seems the realization starts with a higher vowel (lower F1) and ends with a lower vowel (higher F1). Therefore, a more appropriately narrow transcription would be [ɛɐ] rather than [ɛə]. This, of course, assumes the perfect trapezoidal shape of the IPA vowel chart accurately represents differences in height between the starting vowel which is fronter and the ending vowel which is backer.

I'd love to have a more detailed acoustic description of this raised and diphthongized realization, preferably with data on its formats, because [simplified charts like this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/RP_English_diphthongs_chart.svg) may be misleading.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147023/discussion-on-question-by-vun-hugh-vaw-acoustic-description-of-the-realization); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Thinking about my speech, I would say that the critical part of the transition is from a front vowel to a central vowel, so [ɛɜ] and [æɐ] would both be acceptable realizations of this diphthong. I think whether the diphthong goes from low to high or vice versa is relatively immaterial.

Comment: @PeterShor To me personally, vowel height matters a great deal, because it's easier to transition from a high front quality to a lower central quality. The SQUARE is realized as a centring AND opening diphthong, but the MAN vowel seems to be a closing one.

Comment: Diphthongs are characterized by some largish starting area (in English, often central), followed by a tongue gesture toward the position of the offglide. The gesture is rarely completed, except in the most careful speech, but as long as its direction (high front, high back, etc) is recognizable that's close enough.

Answer (score 2):

Different speakers differ in the exact quality.

For my speech, at least, I would say instead that [ɛ] is the wrong symbol for the starting point. I would transcribe my pronunciation as [eə̯], so the vowel I use in *man* is similar in quality to the vowel I use in words like *mare* and *mail.* I have measured my pronunciation on Praat (some time in the past; unfortunately, I've lost the results) and found that it had a closer quality than my DRESS vowel.

Note the development for many North American speakers of /græm/ as a pronunciation of *Graham,* also occasionally /kræn/ as an alternative pronunciation of *crayon*: this is easy to explain if it involves loss of an intermediate glide in [ɡɹei̯əm], [kɹei̯ən] > [ɡɹeə̯m], [kɹeə̯n].

Comment: You make a good point about *crayon* having varying pronunciations, and a better point about why people are sometimes reducing it to a single syllable due to the loss of the glide. It reminds me of [this Brit’s observations](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/OCey25s6M6M) about that word.

Answer (score -4):

I use this Vowel all the time in my General American English speech. It is not a diphthong. It is a nasal monophthong for which there is no IPA symbol that I have found. It can be sustained until you run out of breath, which confirms it's monophthong nature.

Comment: If Wikipedia represents it as [ɛə], they are talking about a *diphthong* They wouldn't make such a stupid mistake as representing a monophthong as a diphthong in IPA. Note that in the Wikipedia article they link to, they say this raised /æ/ is regional. In your speech, you probably use a monophthong in *ram* and *ran*, but not all Americans speak alike. I use what is definitely a diphthong for some of these words. I lived in New York City until I was four, and I still have this vowel before /g/, e.g., in *bag, tag*, and so forth (but not in *ram* or *ran*).

Comment: This doesn't address the acoustic issue in the question. Also: for me and many other speakers, it absolutely is a diphthong, and it can easily be plotted on the IPA chart. (Hint: try pronouncing *hand* while deliberately *not* nasalizing it.)

Comment: "It can be sustained until you run out of breath, which confirms it's monophthong nature." That's just not how diphthongs work. I think you need to do more reading on phonetics before attempting to answer phonetic questions. Diphthongs are characterized by the movement(s) of your tongue (and sometimes also lips) during their production, not because you can sustain them for long.

Comment: In fact, trying to artificially lengthen any vowel is exactly the wrong way to identify its acoustic quality. Some vowels are very narrow diphthongs, meaning the tongue/lip movements are so slight that they would feel absent during such lengthening. You need to actually say them at a reasonably natural speed, and ideally, in real words. Try saying "man" for example and feel if there's any movement. Check with a visualizer like Praat to confirm, because you may mistake the movement from the vowel "a" to the consonant "n" as indicative of a diphthong.